# How to get LineRenderer coordinates?

Tags: unity, c#, line-renderer

I am trying to get the coordinates or positions that are generated at the time I draw with linerenderer, but it gives me an error.

This may be a rookie mistake and I am not using the Linerenderer's methods well. I would be very grateful for your help.

---

LineRenderer.GetPosition index out of bounds!
UnityEngine.LineRenderer:GetPosition(Int32)
sendData_Figura:Trazo(Int32) (at Assets/sendData_Figura.cs:115)
sendData_Figura:Update() (at Assets/sendData_Figura.cs:93)

---

```
public LineRenderer  line;
public static int contadorTrazo = 0;

void Update(){    
    Trazo();
}


void Trazo() {
    line = line.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    Debug.Log("Trazo : "+line.GetPosition(contadorTrazo));
    contadorTrazo++;
}
```

Comment: "it gives me an error" - great! Error messages are extremely useful in tracking down the source of the problem. What specific error does it give? We can't see anything you don't show us - including where you define your `line` variable.

Comment: @DMGregory ese es el error que me esta dando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line does nothing of use:

```
line = line.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
```

`line` already points to your `LineRenderer`. You don't need to say "assign line to continue being itself" ;)

Second: your problem is just that you're continuing past the end of the line.

> LineRenderer.GetPosition index out of bounds!

This means yo tried to access, say, point number 5 in a line that contains only 4 points. There's no sensible answer Unity can give you here, so it throws an error to tell you to correct your question.

You need to either stop incrementing `contadorTrazo` when you reach the last point in the line, or wrap back around to the beginning / bounce back / whatever behaviour is appropriate for your application:

```
void Trazo() {

    if(contadorTrazo < line.positionCount) {
        Debug.Log("Trazo : "+line.GetPosition(contadorTrazo));
        contadorTrazo++;
    } else {
        // What do you want to do at the end of the line?
        // Maybe restart at zero?
        contatorTrazo = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, what I am trying to do get the vertices or coordinates and recorder in a database. Seriously thanks for the help.